# mandar dos datos en un select en laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

lo que pasa es que quiero enviar dos parametros por medio de un json en ajax hasta el controlador de laravel, pero no tengo la mas minima idea de como hacer el select para q me reciba los parametros, quisiera que me ayudaran con ello.aqui les dejo mi codigo del controlador

```
 if ($request->ajax()) {
        if ($request->granja != null && $request->lote != null) {
            $collection = Precebo::join('granjas','granjas.id','=','formulario_precebo.granja_id')
            ->select('granjas.nombre_granja', DB::raw('avg(conversion_ajust_fin)'))
            ->where()
            ->whereBetween('formulario_precebo.fecha_destete',[$request->desde,$request->hasta])
            ->groupBy('granjas.nombre_granja')->get();
        }
        $arrayT = [];
        foreach ($collection as $value) {
            $arrayT[] = [$value->nombre_granja,$value->total];
        }
        return response()->json(['status'=>'success','data'=>$arrayT],200);
    }else{
        abort(402);
    }
```

no se como hacer ese select para q me reciba los dos parametros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Se entiende muy bien tu pregunta pero creo que lo que quieres es algo como lo que sigue:

```
$collection = Precebo::join('granjas','granjas.id','=','formulario_precebo.granja_id')
        ->select('granjas.nombre_granja', DB::raw('avg(conversion_ajust_fin)'))
        ->where('granjas.nombre_granja',$request->granja)
        ->where('formulario_precebo',$request->lote)
        ->whereBetween('formulario_precebo.fecha_destete',[$request->desde,$request->hasta])
        ->groupBy('granjas.nombre_granja')->get();
```

Comment: exacto eso queria averiguar,gracias a ti pude solucionarlo, de verdad esta gente de stackoverflow son unos crack ;)

Comment: @JuanEstebanYarce si la respuesta fue la solución te invito a que la marques como aceptada para que sea de ayuda a próximos desarrolladores que probablemente puedan tener el mismo problema, saludos.